# ObserveChanges 'added' callback on all items, even that already exist in db

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the list of items on page, I want to add listener for detect insert in collection.

*The code below is on client side.*

```
Messages.find().observeChanges({
    added: function(){
        console.log('Message added');
    }
});
```

But if in collection already exist items, after load page will fire callback for all items. Why callback 'added' fired for items that already in collection and how to detect only really new inserts?

Comment: Ignoring, for the moment, the mechanics of `added`, what are you trying to achieve? For example do you want to display all new messages since a particular template was renered? I ask because there may be a more straightforward method than using `observeChanges`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions. For the first one, look here: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#why-does-observe-fire-a-bunch-of-added-events-for-existing-documents

The second one is this:

```js
var isInitial = true

Messages.find().observeChanges({
    added: function(){
        if(!isInitial){
            console.log('Message added');
        }
    }
});

isInitial = false
```

This works because the call to `observeChanges` will fire the added callback for the documents already in Minimongo before returning (and `isInitial` will be set to `false`).

Comment: Second one is brilliant! I deleted my answer because of it :-/
(Though the link I gave to the documentation in my answer actually uses your solution (server side though) but I was too dumb to see it :( )

Answer (score 0):

You can try using collections hooks which will do exactly what you want:

https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/collection-hooks

Unfortunately this package hasn't yet been updated to work with Meteor 0.9 and later.